# How to display foreign key value instead of pk in django?

Tags: python, django, foreign-keys

Here I am filtering staffs which has OnetoOne relation with the django User model.And the below code of function `def filter_staff_users(request):` also works fine as I wanted but the problem what I get is while displaying the organization name in message.I tried doing `organization.name` but it didn't worked. I got `'str' object has no attribute 'name'`  and when I tried converting int `organization = int(request.GET.get('organization'))`  then it again throws `'int' object has no attribute 'name'`.

How can I display the organization name here ?

**models.py**

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Staff(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='staff')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, related_name='staff')
```

While adding the staff_user i added the organization as below

```
<select  name="organization">

    {% for organization in organizations %}
        <option value="{{organization.pk}}" >{{organization.name}}</option>
    {% endfor %}

</select>
```

**views.py**

```
def filter_staff_users(request):
    year = request.GET.get('year')
    month = request.GET.get('month')
    # month_name = calendar.month_name[int(month)]
    organization = request.GET.get('organization')
    print('org', type(organization))

    if year and month and organization:
        staffs = get_user_model().objects.filter(Q(staff__joined_date__year=year) & Q(staff__joined_date__month=month) & Q(staff__organization=organization))

        messages.success(request, '{} staffs found for {}  {} and {}'.format(staffs.count(), year, calendar.month_name[int(month)], organization))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing:

```
from django.shortcuts get_object_or_404

def filter_staff_users(request):
    # ...
    organization = get_object_or_404(Organization, pk=request.GET.get('organization'))
    print(organization.name)
```

By doing:

```
organization = request.GET.get('organization')
```

We only get the `pk (as a string)` of the `organization`. What you need is an object of the `Organization` model.

Comment: I got little problem with this solution .Can you help?

Comment: I have written a logic like `if not organization return something` but after this solution when i didn't select organization it gives me `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` error